# Fail to create a plugin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am new to Javascript programming and I'm trying to learn it by myself. I tried to make a plugin which allows element assigned moving back and forth, but it does not work. Could anyone help me and tell me what the problem with my code? Below is the code with I am trying to develop my plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="#" style="position:relative">Hello, world</a>
    <img src="car.png" style="width:100px; height:60px">
    <p>Hello, world</p>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function( $ ) 
        {
            $.fn.showLinkLocation = function() 
            {    
                move();
                function move()
                {
                    $(this).animate({left: '500px'}, 1000).animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
                    move();
                };  
            };
        }( jQuery ));
        $( "a" ).showLinkLocation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving `( jQuery )` outside the parenthesis: `( function( $ ){ ... })( jQuery )`. Also, `this` inside you function `move` will be the `window` object.

Comment: also... you have an infinite loop. move move into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.showLinkLocation = function() {
    this.animate({
      left: '500px'
    }, 1000).animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, 1000);
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
$("a").showLinkLocation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" style="position:relative">Hello, world</a>
```

**Cause :**

You got, recursive call not gonna break, infinite loop  :

```
function move(){
   ...
   move();
};
```

**Explanation:**

Using `jQuery` rather than `$` ensures there are no conflicts with other JavaScript libraries. All our internal code should also refer to `jQuery` rather than `$`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.showLinkLocation = function() { ... };
})(jQuery);
```

This function runs immediately and is passed `jQuery` as a parameter named `$`. Since `$` is a local variable, we can assume that it always refers to the `jQuery` library rather than another library that grabbed the global `$` variable first.

- `this` refers to jQuery, so we can access jQuery's methods directly, like `this.each(...`
- `return this;` return the jQuery object so other methods can be chained

Comment: Please add an explanation of what was wrong, what you changed, and why.

Comment: @DavidThomas: sorry, I updated thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think what was wrong with your code is that, inside the inner `move` function, you did not have access to its outer `this` variable, which was the target element in this case.

So, you needed to keep outer `this` in a separate variable, so it's not overriden by the function in that function's context. In any case, I think Akshay Hegde's solution below is much cleaner.

Another issue is that you are calling `move()` repeatedly which eventually will crash the browser. You should wait for the first animation to complete, before starting it again.

```js
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.showLinkLocation = function() {    
  var $this = this;
  move();
  function move(){
    console.log("move called" + new Date().getTime() );
    $this.addClass("animating").animate({left: '500px'}, 1000).animate({left: '0px'}, 1000);
    //move();
  };  
};
}( jQuery ));
$( "a" ).showLinkLocation();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" style="position:relative">Hello, world</a>
<img src="car.png" style="width:100px; height:60px">
<p>Hello, world</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what was wrong, what you changed, and why.